# PROBLEMAS CON GROUP BY SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, group-by

tengo un inconveniente al hacer el siguiente agrupamiento, les paso el select y luego el resultado:

```
SELECT (TRY_CONVERT(DATE,BUSBCTRNDT,103)) FECHA_TRANSACCION,BUSBCCMNAM COMERCIO,COUNT(*),BUSBCRESDS,
SUM(BUSBCTRNAM) FROM TABLA_DATOS
WHERE BUSBCBRNDD IN ('MASTERCARD') AND BUSBCPAYMD = 'TARJETA DE DEBITO'  AND BUSBCCACCN = '27649976' AND BUSBCRESDS IN ('APROBADA','TRANSACCION APROBADA')
GROUP BY BUSBCCMNAM,BUSBCTRNDT,BUSBCRESDS
ORDER BY BUSBCTRNDT DESC
```

La idea es que donde dice udemy me agrupe pero no me esta agrupando. Ya no se que hacer:(
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

Lo más seguro es que tus fechas tengan datos de tiempo que están ocultos. La solución sería agrupar solo por fecha.

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(DATE,BUSBCTRNDT,103) AS FECHA_TRANSACCION,
        BUSBCCMNAM AS COMERCIO,
        COUNT(*),
        BUSBCRESDS,
        SUM(BUSBCTRNAM) 
FROM TABLA_DATOS
WHERE BUSBCBRNDD IN ('MASTERCARD') 
AND BUSBCPAYMD = 'TARJETA DE DEBITO'  
AND BUSBCCACCN = '27649976' 
AND BUSBCRESDS IN ('APROBADA','TRANSACCION APROBADA')
GROUP BY BUSBCCMNAM,
        TRY_CONVERT(DATE,BUSBCTRNDT,103),
        BUSBCRESDS
ORDER BY FECHA_TRANSACCION DESC;
```

Comment: Asi mismo, tienen horas y segundos, he convertido eso solo a fecha para ver si asi puede agruparme, crees que eso sea el problema?

Comment: el problema no era en el `SELECT`, sino el `GROUP BY`, ahí no estabas agrupando por la columna convertida a fecha, sino que sobre la columna con datetime completa

Answer (score 0):

Señores, ya lo he resuelto.

He cambiado los datos de fecha e insertado en una nueva tabla con el formato que me han dicho. De esa forma ya pude agrupar los datos. Les paso mi solucion y el resultado.

--CREO UNA TABLA TEMPORAL CON EL COMANDO WITH

```
with c as (
SELECT (TRY_CONVERT(DATE,BUSBCTRNDT,103)) FECHA_TRANSACCION,BUSBCCMNAM COMERCIO,
BUSBCTRNAM MONTO FROM TABLA_X
WHERE BUSBCBRNDD IN ('MASTERCARD') AND BUSBCPAYMD = 'TARJETA DE DEBITO'  AND BUSBCCACCN = '27649976' AND BUSBCRESDS IN ('APROBADA','TRANSACCION APROBADA'))
--GROUP BY TRY_CONVERT(DATE,BUSBCTRNDT,103),BUSBCTRNDT,BUSBCCMNAM
--ORDER BY BUSBCTRNDT DESC
--LUEGO CON EL FORMATO QUE APLIQUE INSERTO EN UNA NUEVA TABLA
select * into dbo.ejemplo_case_info_trx
from c
```

--AQUI EJECUTO ESA TABLA

```
select FECHA_TRANSACCION,COMERCIO,count(*),sum(monto) from dbo.ejemplo_case_info_trx
group by COMERCIO,FECHA_TRANSACCION,monto
order by FECHA_TRANSACCION desc
```

Adjunto resultado, fecha, comercio, cantidad de transacciones y la suma del monto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando pase el tiempo correspondiente.

Comment: Felicidades, acabas de hacer tu código menos eficiente al tener que leer, escribir sobre una tabla nueva y volver a leer. Lo peor será cuando 2 personas quieran ejecutar el código al mismo tiempo y alguna reciba el error de que la tabla ya existe.

Comment: La tabla es una matriz, el cual yo no tengo permiso para modificar. Lo que hice fue llevar a mi area de trabajo(donde me permiten crear y modificar consultas) para llevar solo los datos que necesito de esa tabla. Por eso no entiendo por que seria menos eficiente? La tabla solo es para mi uso, para un proyecto en particular en el que estoy trabajando. No habra otra persona que ejecute la tabla que he creado. Saludos,